# Why does this Linux C serial port code always return 0 bytes read on the first attempt?

Tags: linux, c, serial-port

I'm using the C code below in Linux to read from a serial modem with timeout of 2 seconds.  It works OK, except that the very first time I try to read data it returns 0 bytes read.  Subsequent reads return data correctly.  What could be wrong?

```
int readSerial(int fd, char *buffer, int length, int timeout_ms)
{
  int i = 0;
  struct timeval tv;
  fd_set read_fd;

  if (fd >= 0)
    for (i = 0; i < length; i++)
      do
      {
        if (timeout_ms >= 0)
        {
          tv.tv_sec = timeout_ms / MILLISECONDS_PER_SECOND;
          tv.tv_usec = (timeout_ms % MILLISECONDS_PER_SECOND)
              * MICROSECONDS_PER_MILLISECOND;
        }
        else //Wait forever
        {
          tv.tv_sec = FOREVER_POLLING_INTERVAL / MILLISECONDS_PER_SECOND;
          tv.tv_usec = (FOREVER_POLLING_INTERVAL % MILLISECONDS_PER_SECOND)
              * MICROSECONDS_PER_MILLISECOND;
        }

        FD_ZERO(&read_fd);
        FD_SET(fd, &read_fd);

        if (select(fd + 1, &read_fd, NULL, NULL, &tv) > 0)
        {
          char byte;

          read(fd, &byte, sizeof(byte));

          if (buffer)
            *(buffer + i) = byte;

          if (write(fd, &byte, 0) == -1) //detect unplugged USB device
          {
            close(fd);
            return -1;
          }
          break;
        }
        else if (timeout_ms >= 0)
          return i;

      } while (timeout_ms < 0);

  return i;
}
```

Comment: It looks like your code was clipped.  Could you update it with the full version.  As for the read issue, have you tried polling the device by checking if the buffer has any values before moving on?

Comment: You shall read and interpret the value returned by `read()`.